# What can cause: There was a problem authenticating with your cluster. In Gitlab?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

Hi I'm trying to authenticate a Kubernetes Cluster with Gitlab.
Im doing it via the Certificate method and followed the guide on [gitlabs documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/add_existing_cluster.html)

But it doesn't connect. Gitlab tells me:

```
There was a problem authenticating with your cluster. Please ensure your CA Certificate and Token are valid.
```

There was a firewall issue my boss thought would be the reason.
But now that the Firewall issue has been resolved and the problem persists I don't know what could be the cause. Is there some log file that could help me pin down the reason?

One thing I noticed is that `kubectl cluster-info` shows the url to be a private IP:
`https://10.254.1.3:6443`.
I don't know for sure, but I thought I've dealt with a few programs that only respond to requests within the network when the url is local. Could this be an issue?

I tried changing the server IP in `.kube/config` to the public IP but then `kubectl cluster-info` did not terminate anymore.

Comment: just to doublecheck: your gitlab version? just because the first is written in provided documentation: This feature was deprecated in GitLab 14.5. To connect your cluster to GitLab, use the [GitLab Agent](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/index.html) instead.

Comment: Community Edition 14.6.2. So it is deprecated. But it was still working with another cluster we had. I tried setting up an agent on my personal vps but did not get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the Cluster was not accessible from outside. I found a solution on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61871640/access-kubernetes-api-remotely?rq=1). I had to generate new certificates that also certify the public IP.

First I had to remove the certificates:

```
sudo rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
```

and then generate new ones with the public IP:

```
sudo kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=<public_ip>
```